# Is there a closed surface in 3D such that $\int_{surface}\vec{n}dS \neq 0$?

Tags: vector-analysis

Is there a closed surface in 3D bounding a domain of non-zero volume such that $\int_{surface}\vec{n}dS \neq 0$?

Comment: No. That integral is always zero.

Comment: That seems like a condition required for closed surfaces though. Is there a specific definition of closed surface? (needed for the statement to be provable)

Comment: How about the Klein bottle?

Comment: @TheMathsGeek There is no Klein bottle in 3D. If you have self intersections, the integral is not well defined.

Comment: Ah ok - just a thought

Comment: @gebra A closed surface (embedded in 3D space) is an orientable surface without boundary. Compact ones have been classified as the $n$-tori, and for non-compact ones the integral $\int \vec{n} dS$ is not well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that $S$, is orientable, this is easy: Let $f$ be a constant vector field. Then $\operatorname{div}{f}=0$, and the Divergence theorem shows
$$ \int_S n \cdot f \, dS = \int_V \operatorname{div}{f}=0. $$
One can choose two more orthogonal constant vector fields to show that the rest of $n$ is zero.